# Why is the subgradient not a descent method?

Tags: convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, subgradient

I am reading [this nice document](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee392o/subgrad_method.pdf) about the subgradient method, which defines the subgradient method iteration as follows.

$$x^{k+1}=x^k-\alpha_k g^k,$$

for a $g$ such that

$$f(y) \geq f(x)+g^T(y-x).$$

If $f$ is differential then $g$ is its gradient. This seems to suggest that for any valid $g$, we are ensured to increase (not strictly) the value of $f$. However the same document states the following.

> the subgradient method is not a descent method; the function value can
>   (and often does) increase

and proposes to keep track of $f$ in each iteration, in order to keep track of the best one.

This seems to contradict the first statement about the choice of $g$, as we are choosing a $g$ such that $f$ increases, how can the next $f$ not be the best so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your confusion comes from the fact that you inaccurately read the sign of the inequality. If $g^k$ is a sub-gradient at $x_k$, then by taking $y = x^{k+1}$ and $x = x^k$ the sub-gradient inequality is:
$$
f(x^{k+1}) = f(x^k - \alpha g^k) \geq f(x^k) + {g^k}^T(-\alpha g^k) = f(x^k)-\alpha \| g^k \|_2^2
$$
This means that $f(x^{k+1})$ can be any value **above** $f(x^k)-\alpha \| g^k \|_2^2$, and in particular, any value above $f(x^k)$. So the sub-gradient inequality does not ensure that it is a descent method.

In contrast to the sub-gradient method, when $f$ is differentiable and $\nabla f$ is Lipschitz continuous, you have the Descent Lemma:
$$
f(y) \leq f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T (y - x) + \frac{L}{2} \|y - x\|_2^2
$$
The Descent Lemma is the property which ensures descent, and it does not necessarily holds when you replace the gradient with a sub-gradient.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. A couple of side questions, if you feel capable of answering (or should I open anew question?): Does this mean that $f(x)=-|x|$ does not have a subgradient in $x=0$? How can you numerically check if a subgradient algorithm is converging? Is there no other way than running it for long and hoping the result works? for the gradient descent is easy: you check the direction of the gradient. But for the subgradient?

Comment: Ah, I can answer my own question about that $f(x)$, it is not convex, so no.

Comment: You cannot numerically check that it is converging. What you do have is two means: you have specific strategies for the step-sizes $\alpha_k$ which ensure convergence. You also have the convex duality theory, which can help you verify that your current iterate is close enough to being optimal for your needs.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I have read about the step sizes. I will try to have a look at the convex duality theory, thanks.

Comment: Generally there will exist at least a very large L such that differentiable functions are lipshitz continuous, implying there always exists step size ensuring descent. However, this is not the case with subgradient to my understanding, why so?

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan, first, we do not care for the Lipschitz constant of the function, but the constant of its gradient. Second, what you said is not true. There are functions which do not have a Lipschitz constant, not matter how large you choose it. There are examples.

For the sub-gradient to be Lipschitz continuous, you first need to define what it means for a set-valued function. Moreover, I am not sure that Lipschitz continuity is what you are looking for. You should be looking for a descent-like Lemma.